# Disconnecting Stripe CLI Webhooks Events for Local Desktop

Tags: stripe-payments

I am successfully testing locally with Stripe, my desktop connected and Stripe forwarding events there.

How do you disconnect and stop forwarding events to my local desktop?  I see no options on the Webhooks Dashboard nor do I see any flags/options from the cmd Stripe CLI tool to disconnect.

NOTE: I will remain in Test mode in order to test my deployed Webhooks service.

Answer (score 0):

You should see something like this in the console after running `stripe listen`:

`Ready! Your webhook signing secret is '{{WEBHOOK_SIGNING_SECRET}}' (^C to quit)`

The "to quit" command at the end will close down the connection so that you stop receiving events at that endpoint. If you're running into issues where you see event logs that are still being sent after the fact, I'd suggest reporting that as a bug to https://support.stripe.com/email